# what is the maximum size of a block?

Tags: weight, block

Just for some analysis purpose i need to know what can be the maximum size limit of a block can have like 2MB or 5MB and is there any doc how we can customise it as per our need if its possible?

Comment: for parachains it appears to be 5MB as mentioned here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5239/83

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block size is controlled in different ways. From the runtime you can set the maximum block size by setting the [BlockLength](https://docs.rs/frame-system/latest/frame_system/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.BlockLength). The block builder is also tracking the block size and by default aborts at around 4.5MiB, this can be changed by [this function](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/129fee774a6d185d117a57fd1e81b3d0d05ad747/client/basic-authorship/src/basic_authorship.rs#L157). The upper maximum is controlled by the maximum network package size, which is 16MiB.

When you are writing a parachain, the maximum block size is depending on the maximum PoV size. The maximum PoV size is controlled by the relay chain governance and thus, it is dynamic.

Comment: What is meant by the "maximum network package size"?

Comment: There is a maximum size one network message can be, that is what I wrongly named "maximum network package size"

Comment: Is that a libp2p limit? Given the numbers 16 MiB I doubt you're talking about a limit of the underlying protocols (http/tcp/ip)

Comment: That is the limit for the block response protocol and is set in Substrate.