# EVM solo to para migration on Genesis

Tags: evm, migration, genesis, storage-migration

I need to migrate the state of an EVM solochain (not substrate) into a Frontier-based parachain.

The original chain has been running for a while with high activity, so the state is fairly big.

I am considering doing this over Genesis, but I need to know the potential blockers.

- Would the chainspec file become prohibitively large?
- Would the genesis block become prohibitively large?

Also, am I missing any other blockers for this approach?

Answer (score 1):

1. The chain specification file will definitely be large.
2. For information on the maximum size of a block, you can refer to this link: [what is the maximum size of a block?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6999/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-block).

---

You can also utilize a worker to feed new chain with the old data once it is booted.